# extra characters at end of command in shell

Tags: json, shell, sed

I am trying to run the following script:

```
sed -E -n '/"data"/,/}/{/[{}]/d;s/^[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)":[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)".*$/\1|\2/g;p}' /tmp/data.json | while IFS="|" read -r item val;do item="${item^^}"; item="${val}"; export "${item}"; echo ${item}; done
```

This basically exports data from inside a JSON as environment variables. 
That is,

Here, the key data will have a list (of different lengths) of key-value pairs within itself wherein the key is not fixed. Now, I want to read every key in the list and export its value. For example, I want these commands to be executed as part of the shell script.

export HELLO1
export SAMPLEKEY

However, when I run this, it gives the error: `sed: 1: "/"data"/,/}/{/[{}]/d;s/ ...": extra characters at the end of p command`. What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to use `sed` to parse .json files (which can rapidly grow beyond reasonable `sed` parsing), instead use a tool made for parsing json (like `jq` -- json query). You can easily obtain the keys for values under `data`, and then parse with your shell tools.

(**note:** your questions should be tagged **bash** since you use the parameter expansion for character-case which is a bashism, e.g. `${item^^}`)

Using `jq`, you could do something like the following:

```
jq '.data' /tmp/data.json | tail -n+2 | head -n-1 | 
while read -r line; do line=${line#*\"}; line=${line%%\"*}; \
printf "export %s " ${line^^}; done; echo ""
```

Which results in the output:

```
export HELLO1 export SAMPLEKEY
```

(there are probably even cleaner way to do this with `jq` -- and there was)

You can have `jq` output the keys for `data` one per line with:

```
jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | (.key|ascii_upcase)' /tmp/data.json
```

This allows you to shorten your command to generate `export` in from of the keys with:

```
while read -r key; do \
printf "export %s " $key; \
done < <(jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | (.key|ascii_upcase)' /tmp/data.json); \
echo ""
```

(**note:** to effect your actual environment, you would need to `export` the values as part of your shell startup)

Comment: I don't want to output this per se. I want to export `HELLO1` and `SAMPLEKEY` and the values of these will be the value present in JSON. How to do that? Eg: When I write `echo $HELLO1` on the terminal, it's value, that is, `world1` should be printed. Same with `echo $SAMPLEKEY` and its value to be printed on terminal.

Comment: You will have to source the output of this script in your `.bashrc` so that the values are actually exported to your shell. Remember the rule (a child can never effect the environment of the parent). So a simple solution would be to write the results, (e.g. `export HELLO1 export SAMPLEKEY` on separate lines) to a temp file, e.g. `/tmp/jsonenvars` and then source the file, e.g. `[ -r "/tmp/jsonenvars" ] && . "/tmp/jsonenvars"`.